# Promoted Links Tiles are not showing images that are linked to them

Tags: promoted-links, image-display

[image][image: Promoted Links Image with failed image loading]

I am new to SharePoint and set up my first promoted links. I loaded all the images into my Site Asset's Folder. From this folder I selected each image and chose "Get Link" in order to get the hyperlink for the image. From there I copied and pasted the links for each of my tiles that I set up. It's been up for over a week now and was working perfectly fine, and now all of the sudden they are no longer appearing. I have tried adding the links again but the images aren't working. In addition, I have tried viewing them from both Windows and MacOS and from different internet browsers, and they all appear like this. Can anyone tell me if there's something simple I'm missing?

Comment: Can you share a link you have copied through Get Link?

Comment: Are you asking for me to post one of the links I am using? Or something else?

Comment: Yes just the link you are using for the image? Copied from asset library.  You can also use F12 to investigate if image path is correct.

Comment: As I was expecting, you are using modern experience to get the link which creates an access token.  On the left-hand bottom corner, go to classic experience and then copy the link.

Comment: When I press F12 it gives me two errors, both say "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED"

Comment: Yes, I can see there is a problem with the link. Use classic view to get the link

Comment: Alright awesome thank you! If I copy the link from classic experience will I be able to paste it in Modern Experience? I'd really like to keep using Modern Experience because everything was working fine for a while.

Comment: yes, you should be able to return to modern experience again, but you can use different browser to go to classic view

Comment: Awesome thank you so much! I will go ahead and give it a try!

Comment: So it didn't work. The images are still the same as my uploaded image.

Comment: Can you check through F12 what error you are getting and also paste the link copied through a classic view?

Comment: https://catescontrolsystems.sharepoint.com/sites/i2rtest/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=Soz2pQAPxGqFDZML%2b6HLZdQQ63KVI%2fWtigvUbnvcH0o%3d&docid=2_012f7d690e6e243c2995d5fecb26ba380&rev=1

Comment: Url is not.  Go to the library where you have all the images stored, Switch to classic view and then grab the link for the file

Comment: Oh no that is what I did. I selected "Return to Classic" in the bottom left corner and it changed back to Classic, and then I selected the 3 dots to get a link to the image.

Comment: I edited my post to show the error when I pressed F12.

Comment: Just copy the link from the classic view rather than using Get Link.  The F12 image is wrong it is only showing the CSS not the actual error.

Comment: Even when I go to classic view and just copy the url or try and hover over the name and right click and hit copy, it is still giving me a similar url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ensure that you are copying the correct link for the image file.  If your images are stored in the Site Asset Library then it will look something like:

https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/sandbox/SiteAssets/inventory-icon-01.png

[image]

Comment: I was trying that and it wasn't working. I even just tried making the url just like yours above with one of my images in the Site Assets folder and it still is giving me those white paper icons like in my original image above. It shows the image loading icon when the page loads and then displays the white paper.

Comment: Alright I actually messed around with the url like you have it in your example and it finally worked!! Thank you for your patience and help! The example above clicked for me and I finally got what you were saying so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if people are still having issues with this. I know I did a while back and the way I solved it is by:

1. Go to Site contents
2. Site Assets (assuming this is where you've uploaded your image)
3. Click on image name to open it in site assets
4. At the top click "View Original"
5. Use this link as the image link for the promoted link

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. As a quick fix, if you go to ..

Site content > Site Assets > Click on the image name> In the top right corner click 'download' > Copy & Paste that URL

The URL should be formatted like this:

https://**yoursite**.sharepoint.com/**pagename**/SiteAssets/**imagename**.PNG

Answer (score 0):

I had similar and changed the link to the background image to be relative and it showed up.
so in your example /pagename/siteassets/imagename.PNG

Answer (score -2):

THE BELOW WAS A VERY EASY AND FAST FIX _THANKS

I had the same issue. As a quick fix, if you go to ..

Site content > Site Assets > Click on the image name> In the top right corner click 'download' > Copy & Paste that URL

The URL should be formatted like this:

https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/pagename/SiteAssets/imagename.PNG

shareimprove this answer

answered Jun 14 '18 at 9:15

Airyn Erickson Phelps 
1

Comment: This is not an answer to the question - here is a short guide [answer] and help others. If You want to give kudos to other answers, please upvote it or add a comment.